# PyGTK treeview and row_activated callback

Tags: python, pygtk

I'm trying to retrieve the row data from a treemodel when the row_activated callback is fired.

When row_activated is called, the 'path' variable it passes is a tuple. How do I easily use this tuple to retrieve an iter and ultimately the data itself? The treemodel class has a function to convert a string into an iter, but it seems like there should be an easier way than converting the tuple to a string, then the string to an iter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question, it makes sense after 45 minutes of googling I solve my own problem 30 seconds after posting on StackOverflow.

I needed to use the get_iter function, not the get_iter_from_string function.